# click trigger does not trigger off in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

I'm running a click trigger when the page loads to show an iframe of prettyPhoto. However the trigger does not run unless i use the developer tools for IE 9. 
It runs fine in Google.

Basically it searches the url string for a target text after #. If the text is there, then it will trigger the handler. Any ideas? My url # is - http://www.nvcc.edu/home/ssuh/wall3/#nessie-vanta

```
   <script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).load(function(){

$('#wall1').wallmasonry({});
    $("a[rel^='test']").prettyPhoto({deeplinking:false, 
                                              iframe_markup: '<iframe src ="{path}" width="{width}" height="{height}" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>'}
                                       );

var target = window.location.href.split('#')[1];

    if (target == 'nessie-vanta') { 

   console.log("tester hit");
   $('a#nessie-vanta').trigger('click');
   alert("nessie");
   };

   })
  </script>
```

Comment: You might want to make that screen navigation only follow the cursor on click and drag. I think i almost had an epileptic fit browsing the page.

Comment: I will look into that. They wanted something scrollable on just mosue move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `console.log` which is not supported by IE. In IE it throws error at that line and breaks the further javascript execution.

Try something like this

```
   if (target == 'nessie-vanta') { 
      if(window['console'] !== undefined){
         console.log("tester hit");
      }
      $('a#nessie-vanta').trigger('click');
      alert("nessie");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you can get the hash with `location.hash` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Secondly `console.log` will break IE when you do not have the developer tools on. get rid of the `console.log` and it should work assuming `target == 'nessie-vanta'` is true